# Analog sampling on the Beaglebone Black only reads noise

Tags: python, beagleboneblack

I want to write a script in python that will do data acquisition with the beaglebone black. However, I'm only getting noise when I read in values.

I have a circuit set up to feed in a signal (I was running about a .1-10 Hz 12v square pulse), the voltage regulator limits the voltage to 5v, and the voltage divider drops it down to a safe voltage (~1v) for the analog pin on the BBB.

Circuit:

[image]

Then using a python script I wanted to log the values into an array and plot them once the program finished.

In ipython shell:

```
In [1]: import Adafruit_BBIO.ADC as adc
In [2]: import time
In [3]: AIN0 = "P9_39"
In [4]: T = 0.1                           # or some other value
In [5]: adc.setup()
In [6]: a = []
In [7]: while True:
            a.append(adc.read(AIN0)*1800) # pin value times 1.8 ref voltage
            time.sleep(T)
```

After running for a while, I crash the script and write `a` to a file to be `scp`ed to my desktop. But when I plot it, it's only noise. I've hooked up on o-scope between `AIN0` and ground and the wave form is what I expect. I also set up a potentiometer like so:

[image]

And I am able to read in the correct values through python. So, I figure it must be something about doing a continuous sampling that's creating problems.

Comment: Ok.. but what is the exact question then?

Comment: How do I read in the square pulse and not just get noise?

Comment: Unless there are connections you're not showing, the circuit you're using doesn't make sense. The `AIN0` and `ADC_GND` nodes would be at the same potential.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't connect the power supply ground to your Beaglebone ground it will not work, and you should indeed see only noise, since `AIN0` will be sampling the Beaglebone's ground. You have to connect them in order to `AIN0` see the signal of interest.

[image: fixed schematic]

See the "missing connection" wire. If you don't have that you have no return path for the current coming from the power supply (blue arrows), so there can't be any voltage across the pontentiometer (remember Ohm's law: `voltage = resistance x current`. If current is zero, the sampled voltage must also be zero).

As for the script part, you can directly write the sampled data to a file with this:

```
with open('sampled_data.csv', 'w') as f:
  while True:
    f.write(','.join(str(adc.read(AIN0)*1800)))
    time.sleep(T)
```

When you interrupt the script you'll get the `sample_data.csv` file, with all values separated by commas (`,`), which is easily importable to a spreadsheet or other software you use to plot it.

Comment: Thank you! That's interesting. I do *not* need that 'missing connection' to get accurate voltage readings using the battery and changing the potentiometer. The circuit acts like it's grounded through the beaglebone. However, to get readings with the function generator, you're right. I do need that connection. (The reason I was seeing the waveform on the o-scope is because the scope was grounding the circuit ..duh). I'm not really sure why there's a difference. The manual does say that the ground pin is a 'reference ground,' but doesn't elaborate past that. Extra points if you can clarify...

Comment: If you're powering the Beaglebone itself through the same 9-volt battery then the current return path is already there, it was just not drawn. This was not the case with the signal generator because you probably used the battery or another power supply for the Beaglebone and the generator has its own power supply. Then if you don't connect both grounds together you'll have the missing return path from the generator.

Comment: What you're saying definitely makes sense. But no, I was not powering the beaglebone off the battery. It had it's own power source (USB to my computer).

Comment: Ok.. you were powering the board from the computer but watching the scope with its probe's ground/earth connected to which point of the circuit?

Comment: I didn't have the scope hooked up for that test. Purely reading values in through python, and checked with a basic voltmeter to confirm to numbers. Python read in consistent values (0mv to ~900mv depending on the position of the pot) with and without the voltmeter connected.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't have any connection between the battery negative pole or regulator ground to the beaglebone ground? Without it there's no possibility it would work. Somehow you managed to close that loop.

Comment: Good! Physics is normal again :)